# Fastest and simplest way to set up NHibernate/LINQ without HBM files

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to set up a very simple demo application that includes LINQ over NHibernate. While I wait for an answer, I'm doing other tasks :)

- I don't like HBM files **at all**
- I need to set up a very simple database schema (3 tables)
- I wouldn't exactly like to start from the DB. Maybe class model could be a better beginning
- I haven't chosen target DB: probably MySQL

I know how to create a data model from HBM files. I know how to extract the data model from DB to .NET's Entity Framework but I believe my demo could be better done with NHibernate.

Can you suggest me a quick-start tutorial? I knew there was an old NH plugin based on annotations: that could be a suitable starting point...

Comment: [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) with [Auto Mapping](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-introduction/) might be worth a look.

Comment: NHibernate 3.2 on has mapping by code so that you don't need to use FluentNHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Adam suggested, one option for you is to use [FluentNHibernate](http://jason-mitchell.com/asp-net-programming/getting-started-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-auto-mapping-in-c/) and it's [Auto mapping](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-3.aspx). Although, since your setup is really small, you could use the [Fluent mapping](http://jason-mitchell.com/asp-net-programming/getting-started-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-auto-mapping-in-c/) as well.

Apart from the FluentNHibernate [wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/), here are some resources:
[Your very first NHibernate application by Gabriel Scheker](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-3.aspx)
[Getting Started With Fluent NHibernate and Auto Mapping in C# by Jason Mitchell](http://jason-mitchell.com/asp-net-programming/getting-started-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-auto-mapping-in-c/)

Another alternative with more recent version of NHibernate is [mapping by code](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code.html). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777898/docs-examples-for-nhibernate-3-2-mapping-by-code) has more than enough links, so I won't repeat them here.

As for attributes mapping, I suggest that you [avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769713/nhibernate-mapping-attributes-vs-fluent-nhibernate). They aren't used that much and you kind of *poison* your domain / POCO classes with data access concerns.